# Boost message queues between processes that have more than a single thread (boost threads)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-interprocess

I develop an interactive protocol on `C++` between N processes that communicate with each other via `boost message_queue` queues. One of the processes has 2 execution threads, a main thread that uses the queues, and a "helper" thread which listens to messages that are accepted on one of the queues, and if needed, sends new messages to other processes by using the queue.

Does boost message queues support usage of multiple threads with them in terms of synchronization between the threads, sleep of a single thread in case waiting for a message, etc? The threads library I use is the boost thread library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure I understand the question, but Boost.Interprocess's `message_queue` is [thread-safe](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-interprocess-message-queue-thread-safe-td4512082.html).  The [`receive()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html#idp56401728-bb) member function allows for the caller to block, waiting for a message.  Reading with timeouts can be accomplished by using  [`timed_receive()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/message_queue_t.html#idp56406352-bb).

Comment: Yes, probably the word I should've used was "thread safe". Thank you very much! :>